# custom android emulator skin and keymaps

Tags: android, android-emulator, skin, keymapping, key-events

I want to create my own skin for Android Emulator. I have photo shopped some of the images for the skin.
There are some additional buttons which I need map so that on clicking it a specific event should be generated.
The layout file in my personalized skin folder looks like this :

```
parts {
   device {
        display {
            width   1280
            height  768
            x       0
            y       0
        }
    }

    portrait {
        background {
            image   MYDEV-1280x768.png
        }

        buttons {
                        menu {
                                image   MYDEV-button-menu.png
                                x               158
                                y               957
                        }
                        guide {
                                image   MYDEV-button-guide.png
                                x               1122
                                y               957
                        }
                        home {
                                image   MYDEV-button-home.png
                                x               1214
                                y               957
                        }
                        back {
                                image   MYDEV-button-back.png
                                x               1309
                                y               957
                        }
                        volume-down {
                                image   MYDEV-button-voldown.png
                                x               824
                                y               957
                        }
                        volume-up {
                                image   MYDEV-button-volup.png
                                x               915
                                y               957
                        }
        }
    }

landscape {
        background {
            image   MYDEV-1280x768.png
        }

        buttons {
                        menu {
                                image   MYDEV-button-menu.png
                                x               158
                                y               957
                        }
                        guide {
                                image   MYDEV-button-guide.png
                                x               1122
                                y               957
                        }
                        home {
                                image   MYDEV-button-home.png
                                x               1214
                                y               957
                        }
                        back {
                                image   MYDEV-button-back.png
                                x               1309
                                y               957
                        }
                        volume-down {
                                image   MYDEV-button-voldown.png
                                x               824
                                y               957
                        }
                        volume-up {
                                image   MYDEV-button-volup.png
                                x               915
                                y               957
                        }
        }
    }

}

layouts {

    portrait {
        width     1494
        height    1047
        event     EV_SW:0:1

        part1 {
            name    portrait
            x       0
            y       0
        }

        part2 {
            name    device
            x       108
            y       119
        }
    }

    landscape {
        width     1494
        height    1047
        event     EV_SW:0:0

        part1 {
            name    landscape
            x       0
            y       0
        }

        part2 {
            name    device
            x       108
            y       119
            rotation 1
        }
    }
}

network {
    speed  full
    delay  none
}
```

I had copied the above layout file from other skin folder and modified it by adding "menu" and "guide" buttons.

Here the problem I am facing is that the traditional buttons are mapped (ex. volume up, volume down, home, back) but the custom buttons like "Menu" and "guide" are not generating any key events.

In my Generic.kl file I have entered the Mapping information as below:

```
key 102   HOME              WAKE_DROPPED
key 158   BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
key 139   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
key 115   VOLUP             WAKE
key 114   VOLDOWN           WAKE
key 105   GUIDE             WAKE
```

Can anyone please help. Also let me know if you need to know anything else, which can help you to understand my problem.

***"This is about Android emulator hard keys embedded in emulator skin and not the soft keys / button which is created by any Android app"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu` should be replaced by `soft-left`, as that is what the emulator calls that key.

I'm not sure about `guide`, but maybe `epg` will work.

Source: http://osxr.org/android/source/external/qemu/android/skin/file.c#0122